# how can I can change background color of dropdown in React-native-picker and not able to change that(currently showing grey). So how can I?

Tags: react-native, react-native-picker

I am not able to change the background colour of dropdown in react-native-picker and its currently showing grey. I am using  https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-picker/picker

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }} // Or whatever color you like..
```

Like this

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={selectedLanguage}
  style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
    setSelectedLanguage(itemValue)
  }>
  <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
  <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>
```

Comment: He wants to change the color of the dropdown when open.